# tinybutstrong - opentbs - colspan in excel

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

(Sorry my poor english)

I have data:

```
[
'mainGrp1'=>['subGrp1.1'=>[1,2,3],'subGrp1.2'=>[a,b,c],'subGrp1.3'=>[4,5,6]],
'mainGrp2'=>['subGrp2.1'=>[1,2,3,4,5],'subGrp2.2'=>[a,b,c,d,e]],
'mainGrp3'=>['subGrp3.1'=>[1,2]]
]
```

I like this result:
[excel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQFqD.jpg)

My question:
how to merge cells in row 1 dinamically size, and how to group headers name data?

Thank you!
Andrew

Comment: Can you precise what is dynamic and what is fixed in your data structure ?

Comment: @Skrol29 
mainGrpX -> dynamix
subGrpX.Y -> dynamic
values->calulated sums
Data structure about:
Country[County][City] => [1,2,3] (ordered items)